# Why is strange CSS Background image transition happening?

Tags: css, background-image, transition

I ran into an interesting thing in chrome today. I had a transition set to change between 2 background images, and it works, but with interesting results. I made a pen to illustrate the issue:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmkJG

It happens to fit well with what I was trying to accomplish, but I don't know why this is happening. I'd be happy if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what the 
"interesting results" are and also include some code in your question so that if that link ever goes dead this question is still useful to people?

Comment: Ok, well the image looks like it is exploding as it changes to the next image. Only happens in chrome right now. The code is long, but essentially it is transitioning from a smaller background to a larger background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that it's applying a transition between the two background image sizes.  Since one background image is larger than the other, it's transforming one image to the dimensions of the other, while at the same time fading it out.

To eliminate the transformation of the height/width on the image, just make both images the same dimensions.

Comment: That's a good point; I expect you're right, I do like the effect though, so I think I'll keep it but thanks for the workaround!